# How do I save Windows.Media.FaceAnalysis.DetectedFace for later use?

Tags: c#, save, win-universal-app

I would like to identify users in my Universal App each time they run it.

So I am thinking I want to have *Johnny* open a separate app which will save an array of his DetectedFace(s). Then I have *Sally* use the separate app and save an array of her DetectedFace(s).

How do I transfer these arrays to my actual program so it can differentiate between *Johnny* and *Sally*?

For text it is easy to save to a text file and then pull from that text file, but I don't think I can save a DetectedFace to a Text File?

Is this something a Database could store?

Comment: The `DetectedFace` is just a rectangle. Save the coordinates to a file. Note of course that the coordinates are meaningful only relative to the photo you obtained the face from. Note that a detected face doesn't know whether the face is Johnny or Sally. It just knows "Hey, I see two eyes, a nose, and a mouth. That looks like a face!"

Comment: @RaymondChen Yeah that was kind of disappointing to find out. Thanks for the response

Comment: The feature is face detection, not face recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I will just save images with *Johnny's* face and then generate the DetectedFace(s) from these saved images in the actual program. Then get the DetectedFace(s) from the person in the current video stream. Then compare the two. Doesn't seem very efficient if I had 1000 users though.